# output combines scores from all students instead of just the one list after repeat

Tags: python

Where am I going wrong, the first part does exactly what I want. I put the first student in with scores it converts and averages but after repeat, it combines the lists and averages of[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hm2l.png) all subsequent students.

```
def determine_grade(score):
    if (score > 89):
        return "A"
    elif (score > 79):
        return "B"
    elif (score > 69):
        return "C"
    elif (score > 59):
        return "D"
    elif (score <= 59):
        return "F"
        
def calc_average(test_scores):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(test_scores)):
        total = total + test_scores[i]
    return total/int(len(test_scores))

def main():
    repeat="yes"
    test_scores = []
    
   
    while repeat.lower() == "yes":
        student = input("\nEnter student name: ")
        for i in range(2):
            score = round(float(input("Enter score: ")))            
            test_scores.append(score)
        average_score = calc_average(test_scores)
        print("\nStudent Name: ", student)
        for i in range(len(test_scores)):
            print("Score: ",test_scores[i], "Grade: ",determine_grade(test_scores[i]))
        print("Average: ", average_score, "Student: ",student)
        repeat = input("\nEnter anther student? yes or no: ") 
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing that is wrong with this piece of code is that when you finished collecting info from one student the info is still left in the list, and was mixed up with another student's info

```
def main():
    repeat="yes"
    test_scores = []


    while repeat.lower() == "yes":
        test_scores.clear()
        student = input("\nEnter student name: ")
        for i in range(2):
            score = round(float(input("Enter score: ")))            
            test_scores.append(score)
        average_score = calc_average(test_scores)
        print("\nStudent Name: ", student)
        for i in range(len(test_scores)):
            print("Score: ",test_scores[i], "Grade: ",determine_grade(test_scores[i]))
        print("Average: ", average_score, "Student: ",student)
        repeat = input("\nEnter another student? yes or no: ")
  main()
```

You need to clear the list before collecting again.

Answer (score 1):

After this line:

```
   while repeat.lower() == "yes":
```

put:

```
        print(test_scores)
```

Run the script and enter marks for a couple of students.

I think you will see why it is summing all the students marks in one go.

By the way, `sum(test_scores)` will add up the elements of `test_scores` for you. No need
for a loop. Also try out:

```
for score in test_scores:
    print(score)
```

In general, when you are tempted to write

```
for i in range(len(things)):
```

followed by

```
    things[i]
```

inside the loop, it is usually easier to write

```
for thing in things:
   do_something_with(thing)
```

Your code will be shorter, more readable and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your main fucntion with this one:

```py
def main():
    repeat="yes"
    
   
    while repeat.lower() == "yes":
        test_scores = [] # Inside the while loop so it is new every time
        student = input("\nEnter student name: ")
        for i in range(2):
            score = round(float(input("Enter score: ")))            
            test_scores.append(score)
        average_score = calc_average(test_scores)
        print("\nStudent Name: ", student)
        for i in range(len(test_scores)):
            print("Score: ",test_scores[i], "Grade: ",determine_grade(test_scores[i]))
        print("Average: ", average_score, "Student: ",student)
        repeat = input("\nEnter anther student? yes or no: ")
```